# Give normal indexing to a dataframe which has been altered by set_index()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
    Priority    RID_solve   Prob    RID_prob    Remarks
0      1          5001      34.4%     5040     Caution: FIDs are different
1      1          5001      38.5%     5057     Caution: FIDs are different
2      1          5001      3.3%      5056     Caution: FIDs are different
3      2          5002      74.0%     5057     Caution: FIDs are different
4      2          5002      87.6%     5056     Caution: FIDs are different
5      3          5003      89.4%     5056     Same FID
6      3          5003      89.4%     5056     Caution: FIDs are different
```

Then I use `set_index()` to group the similar `Priority` and `RID_solve` data so that the repetition could be removed. This is the code I wrote:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Priority', 'RID_solve', 'Prob', 'RID_prob', 'Remarks']).sort_values(by=['Priority'], ascending = True)
```

which gives the data like this:

[image]

which is what I want. But I also need the normal index which starts with `0`. So far I am not able to figure out how to get it. I tried `reset_index()` but that just changes my data back to it's original form.

Is there a way to keep the above format intact and get indexes too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then I use set_index() to group the similar Priority and RID_solve data so that the repetition could be removed.

No, you are wrong. Repetition is not removed, only not displayed, so you have to decide if need `MulitIndex` or default `RangeIndex`.

You can check it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[1] * 6,
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

df = df.set_index(['C','B', 'A'])
print (df)
       F
C B A   
1 4 a  a
  5 b  a
  4 c  a
  5 d  b
    e  b
  4 f  b

with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print (df)
       F
C B A   
1 4 a  a
1 5 b  a
1 4 c  a
1 5 d  b
1 5 e  b
1 4 f  b
```

EDIT:

If necessary, you can replace duplicated by missing values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'A':[1] * 6,
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':list('abcdef'),
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

cols = ['A','B', 'C']
m = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.duplicated())


df[cols]= df[cols].mask(m, '')
print (df)
   A  B  C  F
0  1  4  a  a
1     5  b  a
2        c  a
3        d  b
4        e  b
5        f  b
```

But if duplicated are not in first column, only in second or more, then get:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[1] * 6,
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})


cols = ['A','B', 'C']
m = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.duplicated())


df[cols]= df[cols].mask(m, '')
print (df)

   A  B  C  F
0  a  4  1  a
1  b  5     a
2  c        a
3  d        b
4  e        b
5  f        b
```

Comment: Ohk. Sorry I am not that well versed with python. Can you suggest how I remove the repetition and keep normal indexing too?